# How to change background color of clicked component in react onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this

```
const Row = () => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isActive ? 'green' : '#c8c7c5',
          }}
          onClick={e => {
            setIsActive(currentState => {
              return !currentState;
            });
          }}
        >
         hello
        </div>
    );
  };
```

I am using the component multiple times in another component like this

```
const ItemsArr= [
    {
      id: 'list-1',
      component: <Row />
    },
    {
      id: 'list-2',
      component: <Row />
    },
    {
      id: 'list-3',
      component: <Row />
    }
  ];
  const [listItems, setListItems] = React.useState(ItemsArr);
```

For component Row, I am clicking on it and background color changes.
when I click again, background color changes back to original. This is working fine.

What I want to do is, when I click on component Row all other selected Row components background should be removed, so that the one I select, that only should have the background.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have separate flag for each items.
For Example you can refer below snippet.

You need to check the index then assign value to that flag

```
const tempData = [...arryData];
          tempData[index] = {
            ...tempData[index],
            isActive: value,
          };
          setState(tempData);
```

Comment: How can it be handled in Row component? bcs listItems is passed as a prop to another component

Comment: so pass state into Row component

Comment: Hi Abdul, if you want to improve your answer here consider a deeper explanation into what is happening when you set react state, add comments to your code, and ensure that you are proofreading. This looks like a quick answer in effort to get an easy upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be helpful, thanks.

```
export const Row = () => {

  return (
      <div >
       hello
      </div>
  );
};
```

This is how you can set the background color row:

```
const ItemsArr= [
  {
    id: 'list-1',
    component: <Row />
  },
  {
    id: 'list-2',
    component: <Row />
  },
  {
    id: 'list-3',
    component: <Row />
  }
];

const [listItems, setListItems] = React.useState(ItemsArr);

<div>
  {listItems.map((item, index) => (
     <div onClick={() => setIsActive(index)} style={{
          backgroundColor: index === isActive ? 'green' : '#c8c7c5',
      }}>
         {item.component}
     </div>
 ))}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
const Row = ({id, isActive, onClick}) => {

  return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: isActive ? 'green' : '#c8c7c5',
          
        }}
        onClick={()=>onClick(id)}
      >
       hello
      </div>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const ItemsArr= [
    {
      id: 'list-1',
      component: Row
    },
    {
      id: 'list-2',
      component: Row
    },
    {
      id: 'list-3',
      component: Row
    }
  ];
  
  const [activeID, setActiveID] = React.useState("");
  const [listItems, setListItems] = React.useState(ItemsArr);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {listItems.map(item=>(
        <item.component id={item.id} isActive={item.id === activeID} key={item.id} onClick={setActiveID} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```